# Unregister broadcastReceiver initiated in another class in my main Activity?

Tags: android

To de-clutter my code I've moved the registration of a new broadcastReceiver outside of the main activity.

I am finding that my application does cash when backing out of it when the onPause method is called and I have not yet unregistered the receiver.

Question: How can I unregister the receiver from the onPause method back in my main activity? See the last few lines of Lmt.java (main activity).

Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Proximity.java

`package com.atClass.lmt;`

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.util.Log;

public class Proximity {
    public static String PROXIMITY_ALERT = "com.atClass.proximityalert";
    Context cContext;
    Activity cActivity;

```
public Proximity(Context iContext, Activity iActivity){
    this.cContext = iContext;
    this.cActivity = iActivity;
}

public void setProximityAlert() {
    Log.d(Global.TAG,"-->ProximityAlert set...\n");
    String locService = Context.LOCATION_SERVICE;
    LocationManager locationManager;
    locationManager = (LocationManager)cActivity.getSystemService(locService);

    double lat = 39.522006;
    double lng = -122.084095;
    float radius = 500f; //meters
    long expiration = -1; //never expire

    Intent intent = new Intent(PROXIMITY_ALERT);
    PendingIntent proximityIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(cContext,-1,intent,0);
    locationManager.addProximityAlert(lat, lng, radius, expiration, proximityIntent);

    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(PROXIMITY_ALERT);
    cContext.registerReceiver(new ProximityIntentReceiver(),filter);
}
```

}

Lmt.java (main activity):

`package com.atClass.lmt;`

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.location.Location;

public class Lmt extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

```
    Fyl lFyl = new Fyl(this,this);
    Location location = lFyl.getLocation();
    lFyl.getLocationString(location);

    Gui lGui = new Gui(this);
    lGui.updateGui();

    Proximity lProximity = new Proximity(this,this);
    lProximity.setProximityAlert();

}

public void onPause(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    this.unregisterReceiver(??);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an instance of the `Proximity` class in the activity called `lProximity`.  Just create a method inside your class that you call from the activity to unregister it.

Something like `lProximity.unregisterMyListener()`

Comment: I'm confused. I thought two methods cannot share the same instance? How would I call lProximity.unregisterMyListener from the onPause method?

Comment: Alright I got it by turning lProximity to a class level instead.